# Proving Those Are Not A Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V=\mathbb{R}_{3}[x]$
>
> Prove: $A=\{p(x)\in V: p(2)-p(4)=1\}$ and $B=\{p(x)\in V: p(4)*p(5)=0\}$ are not subspaces

In the case of $B$ it seems strange as if we take $b_1,b_2\in B$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ we will have $b_1+\alpha b_2=0$ so I can not find a counterexample

As for $A$ I do not have an idea I just know that if we take $\alpha=1$ we will get for $a_1,a_2\in A$ $a_1-a_2=0\neq 1$

Comment: What is $R$?${}{}$

Comment: Sorry it is $\mathbb{R}_3[x]$

Comment: $(x-4),(x-5)$ are both in $B$ but their sum is not.

Comment: @lulu yes, I forgot that the sum is of the vector space and not the criteria of been in the subspace, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point for $1$ is that it is not closed under addition. If $f,g \in A$, then 
$$(f+g)(2)-(f+g)(4)=f(2)-f(4)+g(2)-g(4)=1+1 \neq 1.$$

For $b$, let $f(4)=0$ and $f(5)=1$. Likewise, let $g(4)=1$ and $g(5)=0$.

What happens if you add them? Still in $B$? You have to find two polynomials with the desired property in $R_3[x]$ (there are linear ones), and use this basic principle to show that it is not a subspace.

Comment: But the subspace is defined as $f(4)f(5)+g(4)g(5)$ how cant it be $0$?

Comment: No, the subspace is defined as polynomials such that $f(4)f(5)=0$. In this case, $f(4)+g(4)=(f+g)(4)=1$ and likewise for $5$.

Comment: That is my mistake, thanks!

Comment: no problem :)${}{}$

Comment: just fot a polynomial that $f(2)-f(4)=1$ I thought about $4/x$ but it is not a polynomial

Comment: how about $f(x)=\frac{-1}{2}(x-2)$?